# Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry behaviour when desired entry is not present

Tags: python-3.x, combobox, gtk

The box behaves OK when I select an item that is present. Sometimes the desired value is not in the store. I want to type in the value and signify by something like Enter that I am done; this should emit a signal so that -for example I can add the new value to the store (after confirmation:). Is there such a signal and when does it get triggered?

Answer (score 0):

1. get the entry first from Gtk.ComboBox by:

   ```
   entry = combobox.get_child ()
   ```
2. connect the "entry" with "activate" signals

   ```
   void on_activate (self, entry_widget)
   ```
3. assumiing you have the model beforehand, append whatever value you want into the model within the signal

Comment: From the documentation I was under the impression that a new entry overlaid the actual combobox. In that case, one cannot connect the entry box beforehand. I will find out soon! And thanks for the speedy reply.